# How do I multitarget frameworks in Xamarin Studio?

Tags: asp.net, xamarin, asp.net-core, multitargeting

I'm trying to master the Xamarin's IDE and I want to know how I would multitarget frameworks for an asp.net project. In Visual Studio 2015, I would modify the project.json file to configure targeted frameworks. In Xamarin, it looks like targeting is determined by the package.config file. Is this the correct file? Can I just simply add a tag that specifies a package that targets the other framework?

I'm writing with NET45 currently and I'm trying to asp-add core support.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend switching to Visual Studio as Xamarin Studio is no longer supported as shown below.

**In Windows**:

[image]

SOURCE: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-studio/

**In macOS**:

[image]

SOURCE: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/benefits-vsmac-over-xs

Comment: Great, just as I find an alternative to Microsoft that doesn't need an account. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @CodeBird You might need an account for the community edition but it's totally free! Also, project.json  was deprecated in favor for the csproj XML based format in ASP.NET Core 1.1 :P  Sorry for the barrage of bad news but better knowing earlier than later :)